# How can I extract a single value, from a JSON String, in JSTL / Expression Language?

Tags: json, cookies, jstl, el

I am implementing multi languages in one of my web applications. The language selected by the user, is saved in a cookie. I have been able to extract the contents from this cookie, this way:

```
${cookie.userdata.value}
```

The problem I am having, is that language is not the only thing I store in this cookie. There are also some timestamps for when the user last has accessed notifications. The full value of the cookie is in JSON format:

```
userdata={
          "notificationsViewed":1509696860036,
          "documentNotificationsViewed":1509696859896,
          "language":"en"
         }
```

What I need, is simply the `"en"`.

In other cases, I  use javascript, and JSONParser to get the language, but I have a situation where it would be brilliant to be able to fetch the language using JSTL / Expression Language, but I have been unable to find one. My attempts so far results in:

```
<c:set var="language">${cookie.userdata.value.language}</c:set>

javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'language'.
```

I need to somehow use a JSON approach, but I don't even know if it is possible. Does anyone know?

Comment: Where do you want to use that language indicator in javascript or in java (jsp) JSTL/EL will work during the rendering of the page, javascript once it is rendered in the cliente browser?

Comment: In most cases it works when using javascript. But some of the old code would be much easier to work with, as you say during the rendering og the page.

Comment: Check my answer below. I addressed both cases there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a project I worked on I did the following:

On the java side set the language to a meber variable that can be accessed in the JSP with a getter.

You can do this using the cookie you set or by any other means (user input, request header, ...)

In the JSP get hold that value and use it for any localization done before rendering the page.

Then as part of the rendered page include a localization javascript array:

```
...
    <script>
    var l10n = {
        "language" : "${language}"
    };
    </script>
</body>
```

In this way, after the page hs been rendered you can access the language as `l10n.language` (in javascript)

This is more or less how, in another context, Wordpress handles localization of javascript scripts.

Comment: Well, this works. Not exactly as I had expected, but even if it is a work around to my problem, it is a good one, and one who can be universally implemented for any similar case. Thank you.

Comment: ...Now fully implemented, with translations and everything. Thanks again